# What will be the value of sub gradient at 0 for function |x|

Tags: math, regression, gradient, gradient-descent

I am learning about Lasso Regression and came across taking gradient with respect to 0. I came to know about subgradient but could not understand what will be it's value at 0.

In lasso regression, we use L1-Regularisation, which means adding the absolute values of weights or coefficients to the cost. So, Inorder for us to do the gradient descent algorithm we have to take the gradients. The gradient of absolute value function at 0 does not exist. Then I have read about something called sub-gradients, but I could not understand much about it. For subgradients for values less than 0, subgradient is -1 and for values greater than 0, subgradient is +1. But I could not understand what will be the value of subgradient at 0, for function |x|?

Comment: This question should go on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/). You can take a look at [this paper](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364b/01-subgradients_notes.pdf). Basically, for a convex function, if you draw a line that starts at a point using the subgradient as its slope, the line will alway be under the function. Note that there can be many subgradients. In the case of the L1 regularization function, at point `x=0`, subgradients are in the range `[-1,1]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I have understood that at x=0, subgradients are in the range [-1, 1]. but if we are doing gradient descent we need to choose some exact value right? How we choose that value from [-1, 1]?

Comment: You need to use a modified gradient descent to take into account the non-smooth aspect of subgradients. Take a look at [Subgradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgradient_method). Alternatively, you can continue to use Gradient Descent (or any other optimization methods that solve smooth problems) and use a smooth version of the L1 regularization like `sqrt(x^2 + a)-sqrt(a)`, where `a` is a small value to avoid discontinuity at `x=0`. I usually choose `a≈0.001`, but it really depends on the specific problem and the scale of variables.